# Check IF Exact Number Exists PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, numbers, exact-match

Inside a JSON file I have multiple `keys` with the name `type` and their `values` are `numeric`. What I'm trying to do is to check if the exact `number` exists. The problem is that if have two `values` with the same `digit` it shows me both TRUE.  Eg  `41 & 1`.

What I tried so far

```
$regex = '/^1$/';

foreach ($value['events'] as $event) { 
    if ($event['type'] == $regex) {
       echo 'Exist';
    }     
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Instead of using regexp, you should be able to do `$event['type'] == $number`, where `$number = 1;`

Comment: And this `== $regex` would never work you would need `preg_match`.

Comment: Further that regex doesn't match anything but just `1` https://regex101.com/r/Wim6qD/1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_column()` and `in_array()`

```
if (in_array(1, array_column($value['events'], 'type'))) {
    echo "Exist";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was typing the same as [Barmar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) answer but this is another alternative. Just filter out the ones that don't equal your number:

```
if(array_filter($value['events'], function($v) { return $v['type'] == 1; })) {
    echo "Exist";
}
```

This would be a better approach if you needed to test more than one condition such as:

```
return ($v['type'] == 1 || $v['type'] == 2);
//or
return ($v['type'] == 1 && $v['other'] == 'X');
```